# Sending tester iOS app

Tags: ios, xcode

I am programming an iOS app for somebody living in a different state.  Last time I finished an update for him to test, he had to drive over to get it on his iPad.

He's all set up with provisioning profiles and such.  Last time I just hit "Run" in xcode and it ran on his iPad.

Is there a way to send him the app as a link in an email?  The app is very small (around 20mb).  He doesn't have a mac so he can't open the xcode file, but he does have iTunes.

What other (preferably free) way could I send him the app via internet to test?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check out: http://testflightapp.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are targeting iOS 8+ you can actually setup Beta and Sandbox testers directly in iTunes Conenct, without needing any device UUIDs, just email addresses. This makes it a synch to setup and manage, without caring about which device[s] someone owns.

Just go to iTunes Connect > Users and Roles. There you can add people. Then going into your actual application, you can assign people to participate in testing. You then just upload your application via Xcode (like you would for a release) and lastly, approve that build for prerelease, which will allow all of your testers to install it.

#### Original Post:

We use Ad Hoc distribution to handle this. It took us awhile to get it all working but once we did it has worked amazingly for all of our beta testers. We send new updates of our app to a handful of people to test before we push updates.

Here is a [tutorial](http://agilewarrior.wordpress.com/2012/04/02/how-to-distribute-ad-hoc-build-with-xcode-4/) that may help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ad Hoc provisioning profile for his device and archive your project for Ad Hoc.